# Java: Strange output with printstream, why toString doesn't convert?

Tags: java, tostring, object-to-string

I am not getting the result I expected when using toString on an object.  (I have inherited the code).

The goal is to print on a txt file the `FiscalCode` of a person.

**Here is my object:**

```
public class DatiPersonaFisica extends DatiPersona {

private String nome;
private String cognome;
private CodiceFiscale CF;
private String cell;
private Indirizzo domicilio;
}
```

**And here Is my method to create and print the file:**

```
public class LoggerPersone  {

public static void Logger(DatiPersonaFisica p) throws FileNotFoundException{
FileOutputStream fs = new FileOutputStream("logPersoneFisicheInserite.txt",true);
PrintStream scrivi = new PrintStream(fs);
CodiceFiscale codfisc = p.getCF();
codfisc.toString();
scrivi.println(codfisc);
scrivi.close(); 
}
```

All seems to work fine but the output is:

```
data_view.CodiceFiscale@43ee5528
```

which is not a fiscal code.

Comment: Sarebbe più facile per tutti se il suo codo usasse del nomi inglesi!

Comment: If you want a different toString() than the default, you have to write it yourself.

Comment: Yeah, whatever @fge said(?).

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels "it would be easier for everybody if your code used English names" ;)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the class `CodiceFiscale` does not override Object's `public String toString()` method, and so you're seeing the String returned from Object's default method.

Instead consider either overriding the method yourself, if possible, or printing out the different fields of your CodiceFiscale object. If you don't want to modify CodiceFiscale directly, consider extending it, and giving your child class a decent `toString()` method, one that returns important information. You may need to use a "*wrapper*" class for this purpose.

Having said that, I think that it is in general not recommended to use `toString()` in production code in this way. The method is most useful and safest for debugging purposes. An alternative is to create a static utility method that extracts all the needed information from the CodiceFiscale object passed in, and that returns a String of interest.

Comment: Not sure why a static method instead of an instance method. (Obviously a static if you're trying to rehydrate the object, but that's another issue entirely.)

Comment: @chrylis: The OP stated that he inherited the code, which suggests to me that he can use the class but can't modify it (maybe a wrong guess). So I was assuming that he would need to use a stateless helper class with a static method to extract the String information needed. If he can modify the class, then sure, use an instance method.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than depending on `toString()` for an object, you should consider adding a "getValue" method that returns what you want to put into the file. Go to the `CodiceFiscale` class source and add something like:

```
public String getFiscalCode() {
  return <string for fiscal code>
}
```

Comment: yep ... and be sure to call this method when outputting your data. 1+